# Difference between 'a == null' and 'null == a'

Tags: java

When checking to see if a variable is null, I have seen that the suggested coding style is `if(null == a)`.  What is the difference between this and `if(a == null)`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There isn't any.

People will sometimes write `null == a` for historical reasons, because it removes the possibility of a typo-related bug in C. If you were to write:

```
if (a = NULL) { // note, only single =
  ...
```

in C, then that would execute the assignment statement `a = NULL`, with the statement's result being the value assigned (ie, NULL). Thus, rather than checking `a`'s value, you set it to be NULL and then checked essentially `if (NULL)`, which is always false. This compiles, but is almost certainly not what you want. And it's all due to a small typo of `=` vs `==`.

If you put the `NULL` first, then `if (NULL = a)` is a compilation error, since you can't assign a value to the constant that NULL represents.

In Java, there's no need for this, since `if (null) {...` doesn't compile. (You *can* still have the same bug in Java with boolean variables: `if (someBooleanVar = someMethod())`. But that's a relatively rare pattern.)

This style is sometimes referred to as "[Yoda conditions](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/)," since it's reminiscent of Yoda's quirky speaking style in Star Wars.

Comment: Great job including historical context, as well as explaining why it's no longer applicable.

Answer (score 1):

For a `==` comparison, none. See [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3) for details. For `equals`, `a.equals(null)` will invoke the `equals` method defined in A's class with the parameter `null` while `null.equals(a)` would be invalid.

However, you could also consider where one of the sides of the comparison is not necessarily a null value, but is *nullable*. In that case (`notNull` and `nullable` are both local variables or fields of a reference type:

```
notNull==nullable
```

is the same as

```
nullable==notNull
```

but

```
notNull.equals(nullable)
```

should not throw a NullPointerException while `nullable.equals(notNull)` will throw one if `nullable` is null.