# c if statement check for zero

Tags: c, if-statement, zero

Is it recommended in c to write conditionals like this

```
if(foo != 0) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Or like this

```
if(foo) {
  // do stuff
}
```

I know they will always produce the same result, but which method is recommended for readability?

Comment: It depends on who you ask. Then there is `if ( 0 != foo ) {`.

Comment: No way I'm writing that though...

Comment: I typically use the first when `foo` is an integer quantity that can have many values, and the second when `foo` is a boolean (1/0, yes/no, true/false) quantity.  Not to say that `foo` has to be declared as a `bool`, but simply that `foo` has the semantics of a boolean.

Comment: The way @RSahu has been explained may seem odd, but has the advantage of avoiding one silly and recurrent mistake that happens with equality comparisons: `if (foo=0)` which not only evaluates always as `false`, but it changes the value of `foo` when it shouldn't. If you use to write comparisons placing the constant operand first, then the operator, then the other operand, an attempt to write: `if (0=foo)` will cause the compiler to trigger the obvious error

Comment: I know all that, I just think Yoda conditions are less readable

Comment: An _exceptional_ situation where I found Yoda style useful was with comparing the results of different parsings: `if (2 == sscanf(buf, "%d%d",...) ... else if (1 == sscanf(buf, "xx%x1 ... else if (1 == sscanf(buf, "yy%x1 ... ` as the return values line up and, IMO, was easier to understand the usual convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the various types that `foo` may have.  What is best is context sensitive.

I favor the first in each group.

```
void *fooptr = bar();
if (fooptr) ...
if (fooptr != NULL) ...
if (fooptr != 0) ...

int fooi = bar();
if (fooi != 0) ...
if (fooi) ...

double foofp = bar();
if (foofp != 0.0) ...
if (foofp) ...

bool foobool = bar();
if (foobool) ...

int (*foofun)() = bar();
if (foofun) ...
if (foofun != NULL) ...
if (foofun != 0) ...
```

But avoid foolish ones

```
if (foobool == 0.0) ...
if (fooi != NULL) ...
```

And I did not even touch the [Yoda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594183/difference-between-a-null-and-null-a/28594285#28594285) style (trying to avoid a [holy war](http://www.yourdictionary.com/holy-war#computer))

```
if (0 == foo) ...
```

In general, seeing code in the positive sense  `if(foo)` vs. `if (foo != 0)`, is conceptually simpler.  And I prefer `if(foo == NULL)` to `if(!foo)`

You not think it isn't less understandable to avoid negating negatives, no?

Comment: Could you please elaborate why ```if (foofp != 0.0) ...
// is not the same as 
if (!(foofp == 0.0)) ...
``` ?

Comment: Aha, okay, but if `foofp` is a number then? Are they not the same? Or are they ALWAYS the same? @chux-reinstate-monica

Comment: @Snakehater _Always_ is a long time.  Both are the same, when `foofp` is infinite  or finite like 0 or 42.123.  When a `NaN` is involved, `a != b` is commonly the same as `!(a == b)`, yet C is squishy on that point (its an implementation detail). IEEE 754 specifies that are the same, but C does not specify IEEE 754 adherence.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `if(foo != 0)` is more clear. It some how also shows that foo is something that can be compared to `0`.

When I see `if(foo)` is `foo` a `bool` or is it something else?

Comment: @joris_van_winden: There are `_Bool`s, and with `stdbool.h` they are called `bool` like in C++. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean